# C - How to check if there is a user input

Tags: c

Suppose I initialized integer variable and I'm asking a integer input; e.g. :

```
int integer;
scanf("%d", &integer);
```

Question - 1: If the user input nothing, how do i know?

Question - 2: After initializing integer variable (`int integer;`), what does integer contain?

Comment: In C, uninitialized variables have indeterminate values. It's good practice to always assign a default value, like `int integer = 0`.

Comment: Please read what the man page says about the function's return value.

Comment: Please see the documentation for scanf(...) to know what it returns on no input

Comment: @bejado: sometimes assigning a default value just hides a problem. It can be better to declare a variable without initializing it, so the compiler can check whether there is a path through the rest of your code that uses the variable without it having been properly set.

Comment: If the user input nothing, `scanf` has been waiting for input. in case of Empty file redirects as follows `./prog < file.txt`， `scanf` returns `EOF`.

Comment: it is also good to read the man page on the function scanf, it does return a value.

Comment: How can a user input "nothing"?  Certainly the user is typing at least one of the keys on the keyboard instead of "nothing".

Answer (score 3):

1. If you don't enter anything, `scanf` will return a negative value.

   ```
   int integer; 
   int result = scanf("%d", &integer);
   if (result > 0) { /* safe to use integer */ }
   ```
2. `int integer;` is initialized to the data which was at the location the program allocated for it. Hence it will look like garbage and should be initialized with a sensible value such as `0`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm still confused of what you said that scanf negative return value.

Answer (score 0):

this is from: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-03/msg00101.html

```
/* --- self-identity --- */
#include "kbhit.h"

/* fileno setbuf stdin */
#include <stdio.h>

/* NULL */
#include <stddef.h>

/* termios tcsetattr tcgetattr TCSANOW */
#include <termios.h>

/* ioctl FIONREAD ICANON ECHO */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

static int initialized = 0;
static struct termios original_tty;


int kbhit() 
{
  if(!initialized)
  {
    kbinit();
  }

  int bytesWaiting;
  ioctl(fileno(stdin), FIONREAD, &bytesWaiting);
  return bytesWaiting;
}

/* Call this just when main() does its initialization. */
/* Note: kbhit will call this if it hasn't been done yet. */
void kbinit()
{
  struct termios tty;
  tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &original_tty);
  tty = original_tty;

  /* Disable ICANON line buffering, and ECHO. */
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
  tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &tty);

  /* Decouple the FILE*'s internal buffer. */
  /* Rely on the OS buffer, probably 8192 bytes. */
  setbuf(stdin, NULL);
  initialized = 1;
}

/* Call this just before main() quits, to restore TTY settings! */
void kbfini()
{
  if(initialized)
  {
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &original_tty);
    initialized = 0;
  }
}

----------------------------------

To use kbhit:

----------------- demo_kbhit.c -----------------
/* gcc demo_kbhit.c kbhit.c -o demo_kbhit */
#include "kbhit.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c;
  printf("Press 'x' to quit\n");
  fflush(stdin);
  do
  {
    if(kbhit())
    {
      c = fgetc(stdin);
      printf("Bang: %c!\n", c);
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    else usleep(1000); /* Sleep for a millisecond. */
  } while(c != 'x');
}

----------------------------------
```

IF wanting to use `scanf()`  then check the returned value (not the parameter value.)  If the returned value is 1 then the user entered a integer value